# iOS webView player videos

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am using WKWebView for playing videos. When I click the cancel button I need to hide the webview. The problem is when I click the cancel button immediately I hide the webview but the native player is still presenting after hiding the webview. Is it possible to stop presenting the native player when its webview is closed or disable native iOS player and use only the player the webview had ?

Answer (score 0):

it happens because you haven't stop the player of web view,you can do this by the following code by injecting the following code

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelector('video').pause();") 

{ (_, _) in
    // Handle completion if needed
}`
```

then you should hide the web view

```
webView.isHidden = true
```

then remove the webView if you have added on the superview

```
webView.removeFromSuperview()
webView = nil
```

this will work